# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' laravel blade template

Tags: php, templates, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Getting error on populating select list

```
 <select name="notificationtype" required class="form-control">
         <option value="sms" {{isset($template->type) ? @if($template->type=='sms' "selected=true" @endif : 'sms'}}> {{ 'SMS'}}</option>
    <option value="email" {{ isset($template->type) ? @if($template->type=='email' "selected=true" @endif : 'email'}}>{{'Email'}}</option> </select>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Parse/Syntax Errors; and How to solve them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this line :

```
{{isset($template->type) ? @if($template->type=='sms' "selected=true" @endif : 'sms'
```

try it like this :

```
<select name="notificationtype" required class="form-control">
    <option value="sms" @if(isset($template->type) && $template->type=='sms') "selected=true" @endif > SMS </option>
    <option value="email" @if(isset($template->type) && $template->type=='email') "selected=true" @endif > Email </option> 
</select>
```

Comment: While the error get resolved but selection is still not working and only first item is being selected

Comment: try it replacing `"selected=true"` with `"selected"` !!

Comment: So you didn't have the type seted in `$template->type` !!

Comment: Is this `type` keyword issue in blade template?

Comment: I think it's just a type value !! is it equal exactly to `'sms'` including case sensitive ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158851/discussion-between-muhammad-muazzam-and-maraboc).